What type of caulk to fill gap between wood and quartz?
We have ants coming in a bathroom through a crack in the vanity which consists of an old wood cabinet section with a newer quartz top. Like many things in the house when we bought it, this partial bathroom update seems only 80% done. So what type of caulk can I use to fill that ga?  Again it is between the wood and the horizontal quartz top. I want to run a bead below the visible surface to seal the quartz to the wood on the overhang area. Can I use painters caulk? Or should I use silicone caulk like in a bath tub - tile scenario?

You can use a latex painters caulk. However you will not be sealing the entrance point for the ants. They will just find another way in.
Try using an ant bait that will be carried back to the nest and destroy the colony. I have had good results with liquid bait stations.
